# Can An Object Pass Itself as a Paramter to a Function in Python?

Tags: python

So I'm building a game, and I have a message handler that deals (so far) with running the game itself, and now the lobby. Every time a message is sent, a new instance of that message handler is created. For example...

from wshandler.py:

```
def on_message(self, message):
    MH = protocol.msghandler.HandlerImplementation(self)
    message = tornado.escape.json_decode(message)
    MH.handle_message(message)
```

Now that MH object... it calls a function in the lobby class, which puts them into a queue. The queue is going to be implemented on a thread, that starts when the program is started...

from main.py:

```
lobby = model.lobby.Lobby()
threading.Thread(target = lobby.match_players).start()
```

What I'm basically asking is can I do this, in HandlerImplementation...

```
def join_queue(self, username):
    main.lobby.join_queue(username, self)
```

and this in lobby.py:

```
def join_queue(self, username, messager):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.queue.append((username, messager))
    self.lock.release()
```

So that when I'm matching players in lobby.match_players I can basically just do this...

```
def match_players(self):
    while(True):
        while len(self.queue) < 2: pass
        self.lock.acquire()
        if len(self.queue) >= 2:
            player1 = self.queue.pop(0)
            player2 = self.queue.pop(0)
            player1[1].player_connect(player1[0], player2[0])
            player2[1].player_connect(player2[0], player1[0])
        self.lock.release()
```

Assuming player_connect is a defined function in HandlerImplementation?

Comment: Well, have you *tried* doing it?

Comment: No, but it would be a while before testing, and I'd like to know if it's going to break my code before I write a bunch more code that relies on it.

Comment: There are no special restrictions on an object passing itself as an argument to a method. Passing `self` would work just like passing anything else.

Comment: Also, you don't necessarily need to run the finished product before you can test whether something will work in Python. You could simply have opened up the REPL and created a dummy class to test this.

Comment: I'm curious, what inspires you to wonder whether *this* specifically, among the billions of things your code does, might magically break?